# recursively scan files and add to array java

Tags: java, arrays, file, recursion

I have the below Java code to scan for all files in a specified directory and add them to an string and then return the string for further parsing. However, I can't seem to get the recursive part done spat. Can someone help please?

```
public static String walk( String path ) {

    File root = new File( path );
    File[] list = root.listFiles();

    if (list == null) return null;

    String dirs = "";
    String files = "";

    for ( File f : list ) {
        Integer x = 0;
        Integer y = 0;
        if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
            files = files + walk( f.getAbsolutePath() + ", " );
            // System.out.println( "Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
            // dirs[x] = (f.getAbsoluteFile()).toString();
            dirs = dirs + f.getAbsoluteFile() + ", ";
            // x++;
        }
        else {
            // System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() );
            // files[y] = (f.getAbsoluteFile()).toString();
            files = files + f.getAbsoluteFile() + ", ";
            // y++;
        }

        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dirs));
        // System.out.println(files.toString());

    }

    return files;
}
```

Comment: change `walk( f.getAbsolutePath() + ", " )` to `walk( f.getAbsolutePath())+ ", " `

Comment: LOL thanks @Jerry06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line from

```
        files = files + walk( f.getAbsolutePath() + ", " );
```

to

```
        files = files + walk( f.getAbsolutePath()) + ", " ;
```